# Среднее число за каждый месяц. PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть вопрос по работе с датами.
Мне нужно найти среднее число оценок за каждый месяц.

Пробовал сделать так, но не получается

```
select date,sum(avg(mark)) over(order by date_part('month',date)) as "Среднее"
from markk
where id_pupil = 10
group by markk.date,markk.mark
```

Comment: вы бы лучше привели конкретный пример данных, и то что хотите из них получить, ибо приведенный код, наверное, только в вашей голове понятен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неясна Ваша цель, но понятно, что не получается.

Используйте вот такой подход:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    select *, DATE_TRUNC('month',date) as "month"
    FROM markk
    where id_pupil = 10
)
SELECT month, count(mark)
from cte
group by month
order by month
```

Я заменил `DATE_PART` на `DATE_TRUNC`, чтобы учитывался год. Но и с `DATE_PART` это будет работать.

Учтите, что запросы такого рода достаточно дорогостоящи, так как создают временную таблицу и сортируют её без индексов.

Гораздо быстрей может быть создание дополнительного поля в таблице, где дата будет хранится усеченная до месяца и года. По нему вы сможете группировать без проблем.

Пример ниже и на [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/63vo1RyCMorMsZLZjUE6UF/0):

Схема:

```
CREATE TABLE markk (
  id_pupil INT,
  date DATE,
  dateM DATE,
  mark INT
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_datem()
  RETURNS trigger AS
'
BEGIN
 NEW.dateM = DATE_TRUNC(''MONTH'', NEW.date);
 RETURN NEW;
END;
'
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER markk_bi
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON markk
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_datem();
```

Данные:

```
INSERT INTO markk (id_pupil, date, mark) VALUES 
(1, '2018-01-01', 5),
(1, '2018-01-02', 9),
(1, '2018-02-01', 6),
(1, '2018-03-01', 7),
(1, '2018-03-02', 9),
(1, '2018-04-01', 8),
(1, '2018-05-01', 8),
(1, '2018-06-01', 7),
(1, '2018-07-01', 6),
(1, '2018-08-01', 5),
(1, '2018-09-01', 4),
(1, '2018-10-01', 5),
(1, '2018-11-01', 6);
```

Запрос:

```
SELECT datem, count(mark)
from markk
where id_pupil = 1
group by datem
order by datem
```